# Book on tetrads formalism and tetradic formulation of General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations

Could anyone give me some references for mathematicians (coordinates free notation, formalism of fiber bundles etc.) about tetrads, Palatini-Cartan theory, stuff about formulation of GR with tetrads?

Please no books with explicit coordinates notation.

Comment: Related, if not dupe of, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270311/25301